# How to Find Element using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

I need to click on:

```
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Envio de Ordens de Operações com Ativos Financeiros</h3>
```

This is my code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="conteudo"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/h3').click()
```

I already tried by xpath and  class_name but its not working.

This is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: Are you sure that xpath is correct?  How did you get that xpath value?

Comment: With (Ctrl + shift + i)  i find: <h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Envio de Ordens de Operações com Ativos Financeiros</h3>. Then i copy the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

As per the given HTML:

```
<h3 class="submenu" style="background-position: 0px -68px;">Envio de Ordens de Operações com Ativos Financeiros</h3>
```

To click on the element with text as ***Envio de Ordens de Operações com Ativos Financeiros*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='submenu' and starts-with(., 'Envio de Ordens de Opera')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and full *innerText*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='Envio de Ordens de Operações com Ativos Financeiros']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```